# HTML5 — How to link an <article> itself?

Tags: html, anchor, article

I have an article tag:

```
<article>
   ...
</article>
```

and I want to link it so that clicking anywhere within the article itself (which I've outlined using a border) will bring the user to a different page.

Wrapping the article in anchor tags doesn't work. How should I do this?

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: I suppose it's invalid HTML.

Comment: Can't be. I ran this fragment through the validator and it comes out fine: `<!DOCTYPE html><title>a</title><a href="#"><article></article></a>`

Comment: When I inspect the article in Chrome, it looks like <a href="link"></a><article></article>...in other words, it closes the anchor tag before my article begins?

Comment: Make sure you have the HTML5 doctype, etc. If it still doesn't work, then it's probably just Chrome being stupid as always.

Comment: Hmm you're definitely correct — it should work just fine. It's just not working on my website, I guess. Perhaps because it's through Wordpress?